# $\int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{(1+x^2)\sqrt{1-x^2}\sqrt{2+x^2} \sqrt{3+x^2} }\text{d}x=\frac{\pi}{8}$ and generalizations

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, contour-integration

Someone shared this to me:
$$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{(1+x^2)\sqrt{1-x^2}\sqrt{4-x^4}\sqrt{9-x^4}   }
\text{d} x
-\int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{(3+x^2)\sqrt{1-x^4} \sqrt{2+x^2}\sqrt{4+x^2}\sqrt{5+x^2}   }\text{d}x
+ \int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{(1+x^2)\sqrt{1-x^2} \sqrt{2+x^2}
\sqrt{3+x^2}\sqrt{4+x^2}\sqrt{5+x^2}    }\text{d}x
=\frac{\pi\sqrt{3} }{24}$$
is correct. The integral has piqued my curiosity for a while but not worked out still. So I hope someone aids me and thank you for the great appreciation.

---

The expression is in the form of $\pi\cdot\text{Algebraic}$.
A relatively notable integral is
$$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{(1+x^2)\sqrt{1-x^2}\sqrt{2+x^2} 
\sqrt{3+x^2}  }\text{d}x=\frac{\pi}{8}$$

Comment: Thank you for posting this interesting question. Both equalities are easy consequences of contour integration.

Comment: The second integral succumbs to e.g. $x=\sqrt{\sqrt{1+3\sin^2\theta}-1}$. (After taking $z=t+1$ in @FShrike's treatment to make the symmetries easier for me to follow, I realized $z=1+3\sin^2\theta$, which is the above substitution, provides an alternative to the double keyhole contour.) Then it's just $\frac12\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{d\theta}{1+3\sin^2\theta}$.

Comment: @pisco I am quite sorry to post all of my integral problems... Since I am actually a eighth-grader(aged 14), I have never learnt to be a really good questioner (for my poor English and superficial math understanding). I just admire the people who have great intelligence like you and the users on this site.

Comment: @SetnessRamesory No worries, everyone was once superficial. What's more important is you keep learning things and improve yourself.

Answer (score 6):

$\newcommand{\d}{\,\mathrm{d}}$These can both be tackled by the same "trick", namely an augmented keyhole contour method. Sometimes this is  known as the dogbone contour, and a more simple example can be found on the Wikipedia page for contour integration, [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contour_integration#Example_6_%E2%80%93_logarithms_and_the_residue_at_infinity).

I will attack the second equation in more detail, and for the sake of brevity (the method is really the same) leave out details in tackling the first equation. I would also like to thank [@pisco](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/257943/pisco) for helping me with the ideas here.

By substituting $x=\sqrt{t}$, it remains to show that: $$I:=\int_0^1\frac{1}{(1+t)\sqrt{t(1-t)}\sqrt{2+t}\sqrt{3+t}}\d t=\frac{\pi}{4}$$

I have written the square root functions separately for the reason that we must be careful with branches. Let $\log_1$ be the complex logarithm defined by $\arg\in(-\pi,\pi]$ and $\log_2$ the complex logarithm defined by $\arg\in[0,2\pi)$. For notational clarity I will denote all square roots by $\sqrt{\cdot}$ but the reader must be aware that I am defining each square root differently, and when dealing with the square roots of nonpositive numbers one must be sure to track what branch of the square root is being used. Define the $\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{2+t}}$ and $\frac{1}{\sqrt{3+t}}$ terms to use the square root induced by $\log_2$ - that is, $\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\log_2(z)\right)$ - and define $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-t}}$ to use the square root induced by $\log_1$.

$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-t}}$ will then have a branch cut on $[1,\infty)$ and $\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}$ will have a cut on $[0,\infty)$. *In combination*, $\frac{1}{\sqrt{t(1-t)}}$ has only a cut on $[0,1]$. To see this, let $x\gt1$ and consider $z=x+iy$ for $y\in\Bbb R$. As $y\to0^+$, $\frac{1}{\sqrt{z}}\to\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ and $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-z}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x-iy}}\to\frac{1}{\sqrt{x-1}}\cdot\exp(-(-\pi i)/2)=i\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{x-1}}$. As $y\to0^-$, $\frac{1}{\sqrt{z}}\to\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\cdot\exp(-(2\pi i)/2)=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ and $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x-iy}}\to\frac{1}{\sqrt{x-1}}\cdot\exp(-(\pi i)/2)=-i\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{x-1}}$. In multiplication, the two negative signs balance so we see that $\lim_{y\to0^+}\frac{1}{\sqrt{z(1-z)}}=\lim_{y\to0^-}\frac{1}{\sqrt{z(1-z)}}$ and we get the desired continuity across $(1,\infty)$. Very similarly, the $\sqrt{(2+t)}$ term has branch cut on $[-2,\infty)$ and $\sqrt{(3+t)}$ a cut on $[-3,\infty)$ but their product has only a cut on $[-3,-2]$ due to double negatives (recall they use the $\log_2$ branch).

Then, calling the integrand $f(z)$ for brevity, $f$ is meromorphic on $\Bbb C\setminus([-3,-2]\sqcup[0,1])$ with a single pole at $z=-1$. We will use this contour (please excuse my poor MS Paint skill):

[image: Contour 1]

That is for visual aid. More precisely, we are taking $0\lt\varepsilon\lt1/4$ and taking a line segment running from $-\frac{1}{\varepsilon}+i\varepsilon\to-2+i\varepsilon$, adjoining a semicircular contour $t\mapsto-2+\varepsilon e^{-it}$ for $t\in[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$, running back $-2-i\varepsilon\to-\frac{1}{\varepsilon}-i\varepsilon$, then taking a large circular arc (of radius $1/\varepsilon$) to $1/\varepsilon-i\varepsilon$, running from $1/\varepsilon-i\varepsilon\to0-i\varepsilon$, walking a semicircular contour up to $0+i\varepsilon$, then running $0+i\varepsilon\to1/\varepsilon+i\varepsilon$, and finally looping back over an arc of radius $1/\varepsilon$ to $-1/\varepsilon+i\varepsilon$.

As $\varepsilon\to0^+$, the larger semicircular integrals vanish. This is quite simply seen from the fact that $\lim_{|z|\to\infty}z\cdot f(z)=0$. The smaller semicircular integrals about the branch points $-2$ and $0$ also vanish, since (e.g. for the point $0$) after a substitution the term  $\frac{i\varepsilon\cdot e^{it}}{\sqrt{\varepsilon e^{it}}}$ vanishes proportional to $\sqrt{\varepsilon}\to0$ and all other terms in the integrand are non-problematic.

What is interesting is what happens on the straight line segments. I will consider those on the right hand side of the contour - what happens on the left hand side is the same. We see: $$\underset{J_1}{\underbrace{\int_{i\varepsilon}^{1+i\varepsilon}f(z)\d z}}-\underset{J_2}{\underbrace{\int_{-i\varepsilon}^{1-i\varepsilon}}}+\underset{J_3}{\underbrace{\int_{1+i\varepsilon}^{1/\varepsilon+i\varepsilon}}}-\underset{J_4}{\underbrace{\int_{-i\varepsilon}^{1/\varepsilon+i\varepsilon}}}$$Since the integrand is continuous across $(1,\infty)$, and both integrals $J_3,J_4$ evidently converge, as $\varepsilon\to0^+$ we see $J_3\to\int_1^\infty$ and $J_4\to\int_1^\infty$, so in subtraction the two integrals are zero. If that is unsatisfying, you can subtract them from the start and observe that the integral is convergent and dominated and as $\varepsilon\to0$ the subtracted integrands tend to $0$ pointwise, and all is well by the dominated convergence theorem. However, the integrand is *not* continuous across $[0,1]$. As $\varepsilon\to0^+$, notice that the integrand in $J_2$ (the only problematic term is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}$) introduces a jump of $\exp(-(2\pi i)/2)=-1$, so we get $J_1-J_2\overset{\varepsilon\to0^+}{\longrightarrow}I-(-I)=2I$. Note that $f(x)$ on $[0,1]$ gives us exactly the desired integrand for the square root of real numbers.

On the left hand side it is exactly the same, and the line segments cancel appropriately, and jump by a factor of $-1$ across the branch cut, to produce (all reciprocal square roots here, regardless of the branch, jump by $-i$ when evaluated at negative reals): $$\begin{align}\int_{-3}^{-2}f(z)\d z&=\int_0^1\frac{1}{(t-2)\sqrt{(t-3)(4-t)}\sqrt{(t-1)t}}\d t\\&\overset{t\mapsto1-t}{=}\int_0^1\frac{1}{(-t-1)\sqrt{(-2-t)(3+t)}\sqrt{(1-t)(-t)}}\d t\\&=-(-i)^2\int_0^1\frac{1}{(t+1)\sqrt{t(1-t)}\sqrt{(2+t)(3+t)}}\d t\\&=\int_0^1\frac{1}{(t+1)\sqrt{t(1-t)}\sqrt{(2+t)(3+t)}}\d t\\&=I\end{align}$$

The residue at $z=-1$ is simple to compute since the pole is simple. We just must be again careful with evaluating the square roots: $$\operatorname{Res}_{z=-1}f(z)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{(-1)(1--1)}\sqrt{(2-1)(3-1)}}=\frac{-i}{2}$$

By the residue theorem, we finally get: $$2I+2I=2\pi i\cdot(-i/2)=\pi\\\therefore I=\frac{\pi}{4}\quad\blacksquare$$

The first equation seems rather absurd. However there is a delightful symmetry to all integrands. If you perform the same technique as I have done above to *any* of the different integrals, the same equations are produced which is rather remarkable. I will apply the technique to the first integrand because - why not? First we reduce all integrands by $x\mapsto\sqrt{x}$ and, compensating for the factor of $2$, it remains to show that: $$\underset{I_1}{\underbrace{\int_0^1\frac{1}{(1+x)\sqrt{x(1-x)}\sqrt{(2-x)(3-x)(2+x)(3+x)}}\d t}}\\-\underset{I_2}{\underbrace{\int_0^1\frac{1}{(3+x)\sqrt{x(1-x)(1+x)(2+x)(4+x)(5+x)}}\d t}}\\+\underset{I_3}{\underbrace{\int_0^1\frac{1}{(1+x)\sqrt{x(1-x)(2+x)(3+x)(4+x)(5+x)}}\d t}}\\=\frac{\pi}{4\sqrt{3}}$$

Consider the integrand of $I_1$. Let $\sqrt{x(1-x)}$ be given by $\log_2$ for $\sqrt{x}$ and $\log_1$ for $\sqrt{1-x}$, so that combined they have cut $[0,1]$. Let $\sqrt{(2-x)(3-x)}$ have both terms use $\log_1$ so that in combination they have a cut on $[2,3]$ only, and let $\sqrt{(2+x)(3+x)}$ have both terms use $\log_2$ so that in combination they have a cut on $[-3,-2]$ only. I leave it to the reader to check this, it is not hard and is really the same as what I have already shown in more detail. Call the integrand $f(z)$ for brevity, and then $f$ is meromoprhic on $\Bbb C\setminus([-3,-2]\sqcup[0,1]\sqcup[2,3])$ with a simple pole at $z=-1$.

By integrating $I_1$ over the following contour (details the same, essentially, as before - just be careful not to include the pole in the connecting line segments, as then the integrals would no longer vanish!):

[image: Contour 2]

As $\varepsilon\to0^+$, where $\varepsilon$ plays the same role as before. Just as before, line segments over the sections where the integrand is continuous vanish in subtraction and line integrals over a branch cut jump by $-1$, leading to $J-(-J)=2J$ for each integral $J$. The large and small semicircular contributions vanish in the same way as before. The residue at $z=-1$ is computed identically: $$\operatorname{res}_{z=-1}f(z)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{(-1)(1--1)(2-1)(2--1)(3-1)(3--1)}}=\frac{-i}{4\sqrt{3}}$$

Let $J_{1,2}$ refer to the integrals over the cuts at $[-3,-2]$ and $[2,3]$ respectively. By the residue theorem we have: $$2(J_1+J_2+I_1)=2\pi i\cdot\frac{-i}{4\sqrt{3}}\\\therefore J_1+J_2+I_1=\frac{\pi}{4\sqrt{3}}$$

Now let's bring each integral back into $[0,1]$: $$\begin{align}J_1&=\int_0^1\frac{1}{(x-2)\sqrt{(x-3)(4-x)(x-1)x(5-x)(6-x)}}\d x\\&\overset{x\mapsto1-x}{=}\int_0^1\frac{1}{(-1-x)\sqrt{(-2-x)(3+x)(-x)(1-x)(4+x)(5+x)}}\d x\\&=-(-i)^2\int_0^1\frac{1}{(1+x)\sqrt{x(1-x)(2+x)(3+x)(4+x)(5+x)}}\d x\\&=I_3\end{align}$$

And: $$\begin{align}J_2&=\int_0^1\frac{1}{(x+3)\sqrt{(x+2)(-1-x)(4+x)(-x)(5+x)(1-x)}}\d x\\&=(-i)^2\int_0^1\frac{1}{(x+3)\sqrt{x(1-x)(1+x)(2+x)(4+x)(5+x)}}\d x\\&=-I_2\end{align}$$

Concluding: $$\begin{align}I_1+I_3-I_2&=I_1+J_1+J_2\\&=\frac{\pi}{4\sqrt{3}}\quad\blacksquare\end{align}$$

$\\\\$

Comment: Your contours are cute.

Comment: @Dhanvin Thank you! I don't know how to LaTex it properly but there's nothing wrong with a home-drawn feel

Comment: Nice work.  I once drew a picture of a contour and scanned it.

Comment: @RandomVariable Thank you. Many of the contour integration examples I’ve learned from, I learnt from you!